# Wireframe modifier misses some vertices

Tags: modeling, mesh, wireframe

I'm trying to create a kind of wire net for an antenna.

I drew a bezier curve, then converted that to a mesh.

I used a triangulate modifier to create some of the interconnecting lines between the vertices.

I removed the edges that weren't corrected how I wanted them.

I re-added some edges between the correct vertices.

When I apply a wireframe modifier, only some of the edges are correctly wireframed.

What is the right way to do this, so that all of my edges in my shape are rendered solid?

Mesh view:

[image: mesh view]

Solid view:
[image: solid view]

Comment: Hello ! It's because there is no face, the wireframe modifier only works on edges that belong to faces.

Comment: Thank you! It might seem obvious, but I missed it. Please add as an answer!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wireframe modifier only works on edges that are connected to a polygon.

See the relevant page in [the documentation](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/modeling/modifiers/generate/wireframe.html) :

> Be aware of the fact that your mesh needs to have faces to be wireframed